# Is there a way to see a graph of visitor count over time for a SE site?

Tags: support, graphs, visited-days

Over on Japanese Language and Usage we're wondering if our number of visitors per day has increased much since we came out of Private Beta. Is there a way to see a visualization of this?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what would you do with this data? Has your site elected pro-tem mods yet?

Comment: @jcolebrand: We were just trying to determine how we were doing for number of visitors per day over at Japanese Language & Usage compared to other sites at our current age. We've started nominations for mods but that's as far as it's reached so far.

Comment: give it another week. If you're _really_ in a hurry to get access to those stats, ping @RebeccaChernoff or @RobertCartaino for assistance with the pro-tem or either they or @Dori or @Shog9 for access to the stats (they being the community coordinators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

♦ moderators and Stack Exchange Inc. employees have access to this information, but it is generally kept private.  Get in touch with a moderator or email `community@stackexchange.com` to see if they will give you some information, perhaps a generalization...

Answer (score 0):

The Area 51 statistics update a few times a day.  It's less accurate and doesn't give you the traffic source details, but you could monitor and plot those numbers and graph them over time.

Comment: So we could make a StackApp but there isn't a way that SE already supplies complete?

Comment: @hippietrail It *sounds* like they have complete and detailed information, but if it's often kept private, then you'd have to regularly petition for them to release it.  At least that's how I read studiohack's answer.